# I'm quite stuck on proving the sequence $(\frac{n+3}{2n-1})$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

So I'm having trouble proving that the sequence given by $(f_n) = ( \frac{n+3}{2n-1} )$ is Cauchy.

The solutions give the following hint:

"One possible $M$ is by solving $|f_n-f_m| \lt \frac{7m+7n}{mn} = \frac{7}{n} + \frac{7}{m} \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then pick $M \gt \frac{14}{\epsilon}$."

I have zero clue how to do the steps in between $|f_n-f_m| \lt \frac{7m+7n}{mn}$, so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you at least computed $f(n)-f(m)$? Can you update your question with this?

Comment: Hint: $2n-1 \geq n$ and $2m-1 \geq m$.

Comment: Ok this is what I have now:

$|f_n-f_m|=|\frac{n+3}{2n-1} - \frac{m+3}{2m-1}| \leq |\frac{n+3}{2n-1}| + |-\frac{m+3}{2m-1}|$  
(Triangle Inequality)

$ = \frac{n+3}{2n-1} + \frac{m+3}{2m-1} \leq \frac{n+3}{n} + \frac{m+3}{m}$, since $2n-1 \geq n$ and $2m-1 \geq m, \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}$) 

$= \frac{m(n+3)+n(m+3)}{nm} \leq$ ??

I'm not too sure how to proceed. Any more tips?

Comment: You're much too fast in applying the triangle inequality. You should first reduce the difference of the two fractions to the same denominator.

Comment: Just figured it out! Thanks so much! The proof is going to be easy now.

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to show that it converges?

Answer (score -1):

Note that $$\frac{1}{2}<f_n =\frac{7}{4n-2} + \frac{1}{2}
<\frac{2}{n} +\frac{1}{2}$$ for $n\geq 5$

For $\varepsilon$, there exists $M$ with $\frac{2}{M}<\varepsilon$
s.t. $n,\ m\geq M$ implies $$ 0< \frac{2}{n},\ \frac{2}{m}\leq
\frac{2}{M}$$

Hence $\frac{1}{2}<f_n,f_m\leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{M}$ so that $$ |f_n-f_m|  \leq
\frac{2}{M}<  \varepsilon$$